# Why do I get a SIGSEV error while trying to use a glut callback?

Tags: c++, opengl, callback, segmentation-fault

In a test program that I am making in C++, I decided to add code to turn when the mouse is moved to the side. The original code worked, but when I added glutPassiveMotionFunc to the program, it gives me a SIGSEV error. The program compiles fine with the function and compiles and runs without it.

```
/**************************
 * Includes
 *
 **************************/

#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>
#include<gl/glut.h>
#include <math.h>


/**************************
 * Function Declarations
 *
 **************************/

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT message,
WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
void EnableOpenGL (HWND hWnd, HDC *hDC, HGLRC *hRC);
void DisableOpenGL (HWND hWnd, HDC hDC, HGLRC hRC);
void mousePos(int mx, int my);
void room1();

float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
int omx = 0;
int omy = 0;
float theta = 0.0f;
boolean gof = false;
boolean gob = false;
boolean gol = false;
boolean gor = false;

/**************************
 * WinMain
 *
 **************************/

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                    int iCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASS wc;
    HWND hWnd;
    HDC hDC;
    HGLRC hRC;        
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bQuit = FALSE;

    /* register window class */
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (BLACK_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = "GLSample";
    RegisterClass (&wc);

    /* create main window */
    hWnd = CreateWindow (
      "GLSample", "WalkRoom", 
      WS_CAPTION | WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
      100, 100, 512, 512,
      NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    /* enable OpenGL for the window */
    EnableOpenGL (hWnd, &hDC, &hRC);

    /* program main loop */
    while (!bQuit)
    {
        /* check for messages */
        if (PeekMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            /* handle or dispatch messages */
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                bQuit = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                TranslateMessage (&msg);
                DispatchMessage (&msg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* OpenGL animation code goes here */

            glClearColor (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            //glClearDepth(0.0);
            glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            //glFogi (GL_FOG_MODE, GL_LINEAR);

            glPushMatrix ();
            glRotatef (theta, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            glTranslatef (y, 0.0f, x);
            glBegin (GL_QUADS);
            room1();
            glEnd ();
            glPopMatrix ();

            SwapBuffers (hDC);

            glutPassiveMotionFunc(mousePos);

            if(gol){
                theta -= 0.5f;
            }
            if(gor){
                theta += 0.5f;
            }
            if(gof){

                x += cos((acos(-1.0) * theta) / 180) / 8;
                y -= sin((acos(-1.0) * theta) / 180) / 8;
            }
            if(gob){
                x -= cos((acos(-1.0) * theta) / 180) / 8;
                y += sin((acos(-1.0) * theta) / 180) / 8;
            }
            Sleep (1);
        }
    }

    /* shutdown OpenGL */
    DisableOpenGL (hWnd, hDC, hRC);

    /* destroy the window explicitly */
    DestroyWindow (hWnd);

    return msg.wParam;
}

void mousePos(int mx, int my)
{
//  theta += mx - omx;
//  omx = mx;
}

void room1()
{
    glColor3f (1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f (-1.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
    glColor3f (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f (1.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
    glColor3f (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f (1.0f, -1.0f, -5.0f);
    glColor3f (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f (-1.0f, -1.0f, -5.0f);
    glColor3f (1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f (-1.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
    glColor3f (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f (-1.0f, 1.0f, -4.0f);
    glColor3f (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f (-1.0f, -1.0f, -4.0f);
    glColor3f (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f (-1.0f, -1.0f, -5.0f);
    glColor3f (1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f (1.0f, 1.0f, -4.0f);
    glColor3f (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f (1.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
    glColor3f (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f (1.0f, -1.0f, -5.0f);
    glColor3f (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f (1.0f, -1.0f, -4.0f);
    glColor3f (1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f (-1.0f, -1.0f, -4.0f);
    glColor3f (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f (1.0f, -1.0f, -4.0f);
    glColor3f (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f (1.0f, -1.0f, -5.0f);
    glColor3f (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f (-1.0f, -1.0f, -5.0f);
    glColor3f (1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f (-1.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
    glColor3f (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f (1.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
    glColor3f (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f (1.0f, 1.0f, -4.0f);
    glColor3f (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f (-1.0f, 1.0f, -4.0f);
}


/********************
 * Window Procedure
 *
 ********************/

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT message,
                          WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        return 0;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage (0);
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        return 0;

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case VK_ESCAPE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        case VK_LEFT:
            gol = true;
            return 0;
        case VK_RIGHT:
            gor = true;
            return 0;
        case VK_UP:
            gof = true;
            return 0;
        case VK_DOWN:
            gob = true;
            return 0;
        }
        return 0;

    case WM_KEYUP:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case VK_LEFT:
            gol = false;
            return 0;
        case VK_RIGHT:
            gor = false;
            return 0;
        case VK_UP:
            gof = false;
            return 0;
        case VK_DOWN:
            gob = false;
            return 0;
        }

    default:
        return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}


/*******************
 * Enable OpenGL
 *
 *******************/

void EnableOpenGL (HWND hWnd, HDC *hDC, HGLRC *hRC)
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    int iFormat;

    /* get the device context (DC) */
    *hDC = GetDC (hWnd);

    /* set the pixel format for the DC */
    ZeroMemory (&pfd, sizeof (pfd));
    pfd.nSize = sizeof (pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | 
      PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
    iFormat = ChoosePixelFormat (*hDC, &pfd);
    SetPixelFormat (*hDC, iFormat, &pfd);

    /* create and enable the render context (RC) */
    *hRC = wglCreateContext( *hDC );
    wglMakeCurrent( *hDC, *hRC );

    gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)512/(GLfloat)512, 0.5f, 3000.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}


/******************
 * Disable OpenGL
 *
 ******************/

void DisableOpenGL (HWND hWnd, HDC hDC, HGLRC hRC)
{
    wglMakeCurrent (NULL, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext (hRC);
    ReleaseDC (hWnd, hDC);
}
```

Comment: Considering this is a Windows program, I doubt you get an actual "segmentation fault". However, it would help if you could run the program in a debugger to see _where_ it crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you calling glutPassiveMotionFunc, when your program uses the native Win32 API? If you want to use GLUT event callback you must let GLUT to deal with window creation and event loop.

BTW: GLUT is not part of OpenGL. It's a 3rd party application framework for simple OpenGL tech demos.